# How to execute system commands in specific order with fork

Tags: c, linux, fork

I have an array containing, among other things, a series of system commands that i need to execute in a specific order and wait after until each one is completed before moving onto the next, the order is determined from leaves to root of a binary tree.  I have been reading about this for days and experimenting for many hours and still don't have a semi workable scrap of code.

1. I don't understand how to create multiple children that can create more children and/or execute a command.
2. I also don't understand how I pass information into children.
3. It doesn't have to use fork(), I just need help getting a tree with execution priority at the leaves started.

All of my data is stored in a 3 dimensional array, with the execution strings I need to run being stored in acquire[i][1] for 7>=i>=0

Comment: recursion? it's hard to tell what your question is.

Answer (score 1):

Without the code or the binary tree, I only can guess.

If I was you, I search onto the binary tree in order to find system command.
Each time I find a command, I fork() and [execve in the child] + [waitpid in the father].

If you search in your binary tree the right order, then your system command will be executed with the rigth order too.

Does this look good for you ?

Comment: Okay, I will try working at it from there, thank you.